# Checkbox select create an array

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a group of checkboxes that on selection creates an array of objects with multiple fields. Whenever I select a checkbox here it errors and asks for a key. I have a key so I'm a little confused by it.

Path: `Form Component`

```
export default class RoleAndSkillsFormPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rolesInterestedIn: [],
    };

    this.handleRoleTypeSelection = this.handleRoleTypeSelectionTwo.bind(this);
  }


  handleRoleTypeSelection(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      rolesInterestedIn: [{
        roleType: evt.target.value,
        yearsOfExpereince: ''
      }]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="paper">
        <Form className="roleAndSkillsForm" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
          <CheckboxGroupTwo
            name={'typeOfWork'}
            options={['Audit - internal', 'Audit - external', 'Tax']}
            label={'What roles are you most interested in? *'}
            controlFunc={this.handleRoleTypeSelection}
          />
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Path: `Checkboxgroup Component`

```
const CheckboxGroup = (props) => (
  <FormGroup controlId={props.name}>
    {props.options.map(opt => {
      console.log(opt);
      return (
        <Checkbox
          name={props.name}
          key={opt}
          onChange={props.controlFunc}
          value={opt}
          checked={opt.selectedOption}
          inline
        >
          {opt}
        </Checkbox>
        );
      })}
    </FormGroup>
  );

  CheckboxGroup.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    options: PropTypes.array,
    selectedOption: PropTypes.string,
    controlFunc: PropTypes.func,
    label: PropTypes.string
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the map method on the given array use the index parameter and pass them into the key attribute.

For example ;

```
const array = ['food', 'drinks', 'clothes'];
array.map((item, index) => {
    <li key={index}>{item}</li>
});
```

> When you don't have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the
>   item index as a key as a last resort:

```
const todoItems = todos.map((todo, index) =>
  // Only do this if items have no stable IDs
  <li key={index}>
    {todo.text}
  </li>
);
```

For more information on keys and lists refer to [Lists and Keys - React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: I read that. I wasn't sure if it was normal to use index checkboxes or if it should be avoided somehow.